# Ubuntu 18.04 does not see Windows Network

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, samba

I have a small home network, running as a WORKGROUP with the same name.  When I go to browse the network from my Ubuntu 18.04 machine from the "Files" app it sees the "Windows Network" but when I click on that, it returns "Folder is Empty".  I have an old HP server running Ubuntu 15.04 (I know I should upgrade) server with several shares, and it sees none of them, I have a couple of Linux (one Ubuntu, one Mint) laptops running in the house, and nothing.

I have installed Samba, and edited it to include the "client max protocol = NT1" line as suggested in "https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390873" with no success.

I would desperately like to be able to access these shares as they have content I am working on at the moment, but this forces me to you my Win10 machine.

System Specs
Dual Core 3.0GHz Intel G3220 CPU
8 GB DDR3 RAM
using on board Video and network.
Any suggestions would help.
Rod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complicated issue. May be other computers samba server limited above ver 1 protocol, btw it considered vulnerable.

Try in Files -> Other locations -> at bottom of page type `smb://ip-of-computer/`<kbd>Enter</kbd> . It will likely show shares of that computer, you can connect and bookmark a share. If it suits your needs - configure DHCP server(on router) to give always same ip to computers with shares based on MAC address. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  That server is already using a Static IP, and I have several reserved IPs for network-centric hardware.

Comment: @Rod_H as this answer helps you, don't forget to vote and/or accept an answer. You can do it later, may be somebody suggest better solution. As you using static(public?) ip I suggest to close access to samba from outside by firewall, only allow your network to access it.

Comment: For now it is not accessible from the outside.  I haven't gotten brave enough to play with port forwarding.  It is a class 3 private IP, and the password is quite long and cryptic, and is changed every 3 months.  But thanks for the reminder to be careful.  I am now looking at ways to edit fstab to have the network share mounted at login.